# Multilingual backend with AsgardCMS via , Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, asgardcms

I was searching in the documentation of AsgardCMS but I can't manage to add dutch to my languages/locales. After some research I found out that Asgard uses the mcamara/laravel-localization package but still when I add dutch to the laravellocalization.php file it doesn't work.

```
'supportedLocales' => [
    'en' => ['name' => 'English', 'script' => 'Latn', 'native' => 'English'],
    'nl' => ['name' => 'Dutch', 'script' => 'Latn', 'native' => 'Nederlands'],
],
```

Every time I try to navigate to /nl it redirects me to /en/nl which shows an error that the page couldn't be loaded.

Am I supposed to execute an artisan command to take the changes into effect?

Comment: Did you make this change in the `config/laravellocalization.php` file? Also do you have a `ConfigServiceProvider` in your `app/providers` directory?

Comment: Yes the file is in the right place. It came pre-installed with AsgardCMS.
The `ConfigServiceProvider` is also present but it has no configuration. I looks like this:

  `public function register()
 {
  config([
   //
  ]);
 } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently adding the locale to the database fixed the problem.

In `setting__settings`, changed the `plainValue` to `["en","nl"]` of record with id 2 (core::locales)